# Astro file browser and Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I was able to get Astro to launch my activity when I selected a certain filetype. However, I don't know how to grab the intent when my activity starts!

```
public class Viewer extends ListActivity{
....
// Flag if receiver is registered 
private boolean mReceiversRegistered = false;

// I think this is the broadcast you need for something like an incoming call
private String INCOMING_CALL_ACTION = "android.intent.action.VIEW";
// Define a handler and a broadcast receiver
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Handle reciever
    String mAction = intent.getAction();
    Toast.makeText(context,"Found with passed context", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(BallLidarViewer.this, "Found with my context", toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.print("FOUND");
    Log.d("FOUND","FOUND");
    if(mAction.equals(INCOMING_CALL_ACTION)) {
      // Do your thing   

    }
  }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....
}
}
```

I can't get any of my test output code to be run when my activity starts. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you can simply call [getIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) in your `onCreate` method.

To get the bundle of the intent, call [getExtras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) on the intent.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but I don't how to grab the filepath off of it (which is all I want). Is there a way to see the data included with the Intent?